# Buckshot mechanics in D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

I want to create a special slingshot that would allow a PC to load 3 pieces of ammunition and fire all 3 at once. As the player levels up they can load more ammo to the sling and subsequently fire more projectiles at once. Are there any existing mechanics for a buckshot attack in 5e?

Comment: Do you want to allow player to target different creatures or hit several times the same target? I do not understand why the number of projectiles should increase with player's level and it is not dependend on the weapon itself.

Comment: What is the exact effect you want from firing more projectiles at once? Should they deal more damage, affect several targets or improve the overall accuracy?

Comment: If you are interested in any mechanics at all that involve loading multiple projectiles or multiple pieces of ammunition at once, that is also perfectly fine to ask about. Just know they may not be exactly the sort of effects you were looking for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Follow the currently existing cantrip mechanics.

Damage or shots that scale with the player's level is already captured by various cantrips, such as **Fire bolt** or **Eldritch blast**.

An item that, *as an action* (note, not as an attack otherwise you'd get weird interactions with the **Extra attack** feature,) allows to fire 1, 2, 3 or 4 clusters of buckshot to a target/multiple targets as desired, depending on the level of the user, wouldn't introduce anything more game-breaking than a **Wand of Eldritch blasts**.

As a side note I wouldn't recommend to track individual buckshot pellets. Shotguns still fire fairly tight spreads, much more accurately than what videogames trained us to believe. A 2d6, or 3d4 if you want to roll fancier dice, base damage roll for a buckshot cluster (or any multi-dice solution that doesn't use larger dice as base) should be fairly reasonable as a starting point.

Comment: Can I get some clarification on why I got so many downvotes?